# Stream Reader and Writer Conflict

Tags: vb.net, stream, streamreader, streamwriter

I am making a class that is to help with saving some strings to a local text file (I want to append them to that file and not overwrite so that it is a log file). When I write with the streamwriter to find the end of the previous text, I get an error "the file is not available as it is being used by another process". I looked into this problem on MSDN and I got very little help. I tried to eliminate some variables so I removed the streamreader to check was that the problem and it was. When I tried to write to the file then it worked and I got no error so this made me come to the conclusion that the problem arose in the streamreader. But I could not figure out why?

Here is the code:

```
 Public Sub SaveFile(ByVal Task As String, ByVal Difficulty As Integer, ByVal Time_Taken As String)
    Dim SW As String = "C:/Program Files/Business Elements/Dashboard System Files/UserWorkEthic.txt"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim aryText(3) As String
    aryText(0) = Task
    aryText(1) = Difficulty
    aryText(2) = Time_Taken
    Dim objWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(SW, True)
    Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(SW, True)
    reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.EndOfStream.ToString()
    For i = 0 To 3
        objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(reader.EndOfStream + i))
    Next
    reader.Close()

    objWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joel has commented on the previous answer it is possible to change the type of locking.

Otherwise building on what Neil has suggested, if to try to write to a file with a new reader it is difficult not to lose the information already within the file.

I would suggest you rename the original file to a temporary name, `"UserWorkEthicTEMP.txt"` for example. Create a new text file with the original name. Now; read a line, write a line, between the two files, before adding your new data onto the end. Finally Delete the temporary file and you will have the new file with the new details. If you have an error the temporary file will serve as a backup of the original. Some sample code below:

`Change file names`

```
Dim Line as string
line=Reader.readline
Do until Line=nothing    
objwriter.writeline(line)
line=reader.readline
loop
```

`add new values on the end and remove old file`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `read` and `write` to the same file and this is causing a `lock` contention.  Either store the contents of the file into a variable and then write it back out including your new data to the file.

```
Psuedo

Reader.Open file
String content = Reader.ReadToEnd()
Reader.Close

Writer.Open file
Loop
    Writer.Write newContent
Writer.Close
```

Comment: You can read and write to the same file. It depends on what kind of locking behavior you specified when opening it.

Comment: Thanks Neil :)

Would I do something like 

Dim str as string = reader.readtoend 
reader.close

writer.write(str & newContent)

But how would I code it to go to a new line for the newContent after writing the old text?